# WordPress karma theme shortcodes not working

Tags: theme-options

I have uploaded karma theme and, but due to some reason, images using timthumb are not displaying. My WordPress url is http://wordpressforpi.com/test/ in this page, second image does not shows up, if we try to see through firebug, image url for second image, it shows

> http://wordpressforpi.com/wp-content/themes/Karma/truethemes_framework/extended/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://wordpressforpi.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/google-adwords-e1320816486813.jpg&h=145&w=275

I tried the same process on other server as well as on my local pc, works well. Can you please help me.

Comment: Are you aware that [your domain name violates the WordPress trademark policy](http://wordpress.org/about/domains/)?

Answer (score 1):

In the theme folder there is probably a folder called cache where timthumb stores the images it creates. Make sure this is writable, as otherwise timthumb can't put it's images anywhere and simply fails to load anything.

Comment: No, i have even tried by doing a fresh wordpress installation and uploaded the theme, but still it didn't worked on this server, it is working fine on other server as well as my local pc.

Comment: Well the fact that it works on other servers makes me suspect my answer is correct. The folder may not be called cache but there will be a folder somewhere in your theme that timthumb uses to store previously created images. This folder needs to be writable - when I've solved this problem in the past I always set to 777 - it may not need to be that liberal. Also Karma is a premium theme so the better place to ask for solutions is in the comments on theme forest where the author will be able to help you out directly.